# Long click confirmation (vibration)

Tags: android, vibration, long-click

In my app, some views react to `onLongClick`.  In others, I want to achieve the same functionality, but I want to know which part of the view was long-clicked -- so I'm simulating it with `onTouchEvent`.  The default device behavior on the long click is vibration.  I would like to do the same on a *simulated* long click.

I know how to get permission for the vibrator and do whatever I want with it.  Is that the only way?  I'm looking for a function that does a "default" vibrate, like `playSoundEffect` plays a handful of default system sounds.  Basically, all I want to do is perform a default system reaction to a long click.  It may not even be vibration on some devices...

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `onLongClick` just return **`true`** and it will confirmed (vibrate).
When returnning `false` it will not vibrate.

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
            {
                @Override public boolean onLongClick(View view)
                {
                    doSomething();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: On some devices the confirmation vibration is disabled. On Samsung Galaxy S10 for example.